# MySQL Query Help - Get MAX(Date)

Tags: mysql

I have table as shown below:

| Type | Value_1 | Value_2 | Standby_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 20 | 2022-06-01 |
| A | 100 | 40 | 2022-06-06 |
| A | 200 | 60 | 2022-06-03 |
| B | 300 | 80 | 2022-06-04 |
| B | 400 | 100 | 2022-06-09 |

I am trying to get sum of value_1 and value_2 with the latest standby date where type = A in one query. Thus, the result will be as shown below:

| Type | SUM(Value_1) | SUM(Value_2) | Standby_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 350 | 120 | 2022-06-06 |

Would like to know what is the query to achieved the above result. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `max` to get the greatest date in a group, and `sum` to get the totals:

```
select type, sum(value_1), sum(value_2), max(standby_date)
from t
where type = 'a'
group by type
```

Comment: Your new SO profile pics looks great +1.

Comment: In MySQL `group by type` is obviously excess because of `where type = 'a'` - the whole filtered rowset to be aggregated is one group.

Comment: @akina yes but I added it so that type could be added to select clause, to match expected result in OP.

Comment: I.e. you predict that the filtering condition may contain a list of values, and your code is a pattern? In such case `where type IN ('a')` may be more reasonable.